# url made in jquery both redirect to and opens a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#resultsDiv').on('click', '#seeTemplates', function () {
    var ebayTemplate = $('#templates').val();

    var url = '@Url.Action("SeeTemplateDetailsByName", "EbayTemplate")';

    window.location.href = url + "?templateName=" + ebayTemplate;
});
```

This code function well but it has a side effet that surprises me: as I click on the link a new tab opens with the good link. But the main windows also loads the good url. Why does it open a new window?

*EDIT*

New code as per requested:

```
    $('#resultsDiv').on('click', '#seeTemplates', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("Clicked");

        var ebayTemplate = $('#templates').val();

        var url = '@Url.Action("SeeTemplateDetailsByName", "EbayTemplate")';

        window.location.href = url + "?templateName=" + ebayTemplate;
    });
```

I'm now investigating on 2 possibilities:

1. Can a delegate have this kind of result?
2. Is it the normal behavior of a `windows.location.href` jquery call?

Comment: Is `#seeTemplates` an `<a>` element?

Comment: Yes it is! Does an anchor has this type of behavior?

Comment: Maybe you have target="_blank" on the <a href="#" target="_blank">. That will cause it to open in a new window.

Comment: Nope, I have checked this issue in case and the anchor is like this: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="seeTemplates">See template</a>`

Comment: @Rex - it's likely you `a` inside a form, and it causes a form submission. For this you want to prevent that default behaviour, see FirstLegion's answer.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the additional code and just leave e.preventDefault() in there. Does it still open in a new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, adding the function(e) and e.preventDefault() will stop the browser's default action:

```
$('#resultsDiv').on('click', '#seeTemplates', function (e) {
    var ebayTemplate = $('#templates').val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("SeeTemplateDetailsByName", "EbayTemplate")';
    window.location.href = url + "?templateName=" + ebayTemplate;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Strangely, this does not stops the behavior, although I understand that your code should indeed stop it. :|

Comment: Exactly the same as yours.

Comment: Please post anyway, just to make sure.

Comment: Silly me! Had another piece of code that interacted in the same way. Removed that other piece, left yours, and everything works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment (due to being new here) so you might want to try to add `e.preventDefault()` there to prevent / block the default action (there are other ways too)

If you want to open a new tab with JavaScript try this;

```
$('#resultsDiv').on('click', '#seeTemplates', function (e) {
    // Prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    var ebayTemplate = $('#templates').val();

    var url = '@Url.Action("SeeTemplateDetailsByName", "EbayTemplate")';

    // Open in new tab
    var win = window.open(url + "?templateName=" + ebayTemplate, "_blank");
    // Focus on new tab.
    win.focus();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because `#seeTemplates` is a link (per OP comment), both the default link action and your custom event handler are running. To avoid that, you'll need to prevent the default behavior of the link:

```
$('#resultsDiv').on('click', '#seeTemplates', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ebayTemplate = $('#templates').val();

    var url = '@Url.Action("SeeTemplateDetailsByName", "EbayTemplate")';

    window.location.href = url + "?templateName=" + ebayTemplate;
});
```

You could also just change the element to be some other type (perhaps a `<span>`), and avoid the problem altogether.